# Python 3: How can I make my Text-based game windowed?

Tags: gui, python, text-based

I've been making a text-based RPG in Python, and I'm a bit lost in transitioning from a console to a window.

I'm not trying to do anything fancy (I think). I'd like my text to display normally, as it would in the console.

This is a good example: http://inventwithpython.com/blogstatic/esotera.png?27f655

However, I'd like to load images so that my different locations have corresponding backgrounds (I.e. When the character enters a tavern, the background is a tavern).

I have Pygame installed, but I really have no idea where to go from here, and I can't find any tutorials for text-based games like this.

My game code is here if you'd like to take a look:

https://gist.github.com/NervousTumbleweed/f42f325982f2sf2549b528ce0156j34a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python's `pygame` library, which is used to make video games, and handles GUI as well. Here's a small [example (Nerd Paradise PyGame Tutorial)](https://nerdparadise.com/programming/pygame/part1):

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
done = False

while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        done = True

        pygame.display.flip()
```

Using this example, you can create your own window, and draw graphics into it. To draw a simple rectangle you use

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 128, 255), pygame.Rect(30, 30, 60, 60))
```

Once you get used to it, you can learn how to draw Sprites and text and complete something similar to the screenshot you provided, including images as background. Take a look at [Nerd Paradise's tutorial](https://nerdparadise.com/programming/pygame/part1) for more in-depth of `pygame` and what you can do with it.